# PKCS#11 C_Encrypt fails with Bad Arguments for 128 bit AES key

Tags: pkcs#11

I generate a 128-bit AES object using "C_CreateObject". 
I then do the following to encrypt a piece of data and get a "Bad Argumnents" error on the call to "C_Encrypt" to get the encrypted data length.

```
char clear[] = "My name is Eric!";
buf_len = sizeof(clear) -1;

rv = pfunc11->C_EncryptInit(session, pMechanism, hObject);

if (rv != CKR_OK)    
{
    printf("ERROR: rv=0x%08X: initializing encryption:\n", (unsigned int)rv);
    return false;
}


rv = pfunc11->C_Encrypt(session, (CK_BYTE_PTR)clear, (CK_ULONG)buf_len, NULL, pulEncryptedDataLen);
if (rv != CKR_OK) 
{                                   
    printf("ERROR: rv=0x%08X: derror getting encryption data buffer length:\n", (unsigned int)rv);
    return false;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Here is my mechanism definition -

```
CK_MECHANISM myMechanism = {CKM_AES_CBC_PAD, (CK_VOID_PTR)"01020304050607081122334455667788", (CK_ULONG)16};
CK_MECHANISM_PTR pMechanism = &myMechanism;
```

Comment: Clearly the length of the clear text is not the issue here according to this - https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v211/group__SEC__12__19__4__AES__CBC__WITH__PKCS__PADDING.html  .. The mechanism CKM_AES_CBC_PAD allows for any input length and will round it up to next block size. What could be the bad argument here ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `pulEncryptedDataLen` is probably NULL which causes `CKR_ARGUMENTS_BAD`.

It is better to use e.g.:

```
CK_ULONG ulEncryptedDataLen;
...
rv = pfunc11->C_Encrypt(session, (CK_BYTE_PTR)clear, (CK_ULONG)buf_len, NULL, &ulEncryptedDataLen);
```

The number of bytes sufficient to store encryption result of a single-part encryption gets stored into `ulEncryptedDataLen`.

Also please note that your way of passing IV value is not correct as `"01020304050607081122334455667788"` results in an ASCII string (giving IV as `30313032303330343035303630373038` -- which is probably not what you want).

To get correct IV use `"\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55\x66\x77\x88"` instead.

Good luck!